# How to select state based on country selection in rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

I have 2 tables in DB, Countries and States. Now, When I select Countries based on selection it must show the states.

for Country selection in .rhtml file i am using as below:

```
<%= select_tag "User[country_id]", options_for_select(Country.all.collect{|x| [x.country,x.id]})%>
```

now based on above selection i need to select the states.

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
<%= select_tag
  :country_select, # name of selectbox
  options_from_collection_for_select(@myrecords, "id", "name"), # your options for this select box
  :'data-remote' => 'true', # important for UJS
  :'data-url' => url_for(:controller => 'MyController', :action => 'getdata'), # we get the data from here!
  :'data-type' => 'json' # tell jQuery to parse the response as JSON!
%>


<%= select_tag
  :state_select, # name of selectbox
  "<option>Please select something from country select!</option>"
%>
```

Controller:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def getdata
    # this contains what has been selected in the first select box
    @data_from_country_select = params[:country_select]

    # we get the data for selectbox 2
    @data_for_state_select = MyModel.where(:some_id => @data_from_country_select).all

    # render an array in JSON containing arrays like:
    # [[:id1, :name1], [:id2, :name2]]
    render :json => @data_for_state_select.map{|c| [c.id, c.name]}
  end
end
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // #country_select is the id of our first select box, if the ajax request has been successful,
  // an ajax:success event is triggered.

  $('#country_select').live('ajax:success', function(evt, data, status, xhr) {
    // get second selectbox by its id
    var selectbox2 = $('#state_select');

    // empty it
    selectbox2.empty();

    // we got a JSON array in data, iterate through it

    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
      // append an option
      var opt = $('<option/>');

      // value is an array: [:id, :name]
      opt.attr('value', value[0]);
      // set text
      opt.text(value[1]);
      // append to select
      opt.appendTo(selectbox2);
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will update the answer to include only essential part.

Comment: go ahead and make it meaningful

Comment: live('ajax:success', function(evt, data, status, xhr) is not working and rising an error.

States data is not retrieving based on Country selection.

Bootstrap errors are rising by using this.

Answer (score 0):

I personally never tried myself this way, Try this code in side the country dropdown.

```
"f.select_tag :state, State.where(country_id: c.id)"


<div class="field">
   <%= f.label :country %><br>
   <%= f.select :country_id, Country.all.map {|c| [c.name, c.id] }, {prompt:"Choose Country"} %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `ajax` to get the updated `states`, like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :countries do
   get :state, on: :member #-> url.com/countries/:country_id/states/
end
```

You'll have to add a `states` action to your `countries` controller:

```
#app/controllers/countries_controller.rb
class CountriesController < ApplicationController
   def states
      @country = Country.find params[:country_id]
      @states = @country.states
      respond_to do |format|
         format.json { render json: @states.to_json }
      end
   end
end
```

This will allow you to send an ajax request to this controller when you change the value of the `select`:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("change", "#countries", function(e){
   url = "countries/" + $(this).val() + "/states";
   $.get(url, function(data){
      $.each(data,function(key, value){
         $("#states").find('option').remove().end();
         $("#states").append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
      });
   }, "json")
});
```

--

You'll also want to make sure your form is properly formatted.

Specifically, you'll want to use `form_for` instead of `form_tag`:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :country_id, Country.all, :id, :name %>
<% end %>
```